# How to mock objects methods return value

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-mock

what I currently have is:

```
def some_method():
    some_obj = some_other_method()
    # This is what I want to mock return value of:
    some_obj.some_obj_some_method()

@patch('some_package.some_other_method')
def test_some_stuff(some_other_method_patch):
    some_other_method_patch.return_value = SomeObject()
```

How could I get about setting some_obj.some_obj_some_method() return value to False?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`patch('some_package.some_other_method')` will replace the function `some_other_method` with a `Mock`. Now you need to replace the return value of the method `some_obj_some_method` of this mock:

```
mock.return_value.some_obj_some_method.return_value = False
```

The complete example:

```
# some_package.py

class SomeObject:
    def some_obj_some_method(self):
        raise RuntimeError()


def some_other_method():
    return SomeObject()


def some_method():
    some_obj = some_other_method()
    # This is what you want to mock return value of:
    return some_obj.some_obj_some_method()
```

Test:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from some_package import SomeObject, some_method

@patch('some_package.some_other_method')
def test_some_stuff(function_mock):
    function_mock.return_value.some_obj_some_method.return_value = False
    assert not some_method()
```

The test will pass as is, will raise a `RuntimeError` without patching and fail the assertion without the line `function_mock.return_value.some_obj_some_method.return_value = False` because `some_method` will only return a `Mock` that is never `False`.

Comment: Is there a way to mock multiple return values from `some_obj_some_method`? For example, the first time return True and the second time return False? I don't think assigning an iterable works like it does with patch's `side_effect` feature.

Comment: @chrisinmtown IIRC this should be doable in a similar manner as with `return_value`, by assigning an iterable to `some_obj_some_method.side_effect`. Did you try it?

Comment: yes I tried it, please see the answer I posted to this question that assigns a list to `mock_pymisp.return_value.organisations.return_value` When I run that I don't see the special multi-return value behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `patch.object`

```
import mock
import some_obj
@mock.patch.object(some_obj, "some_obj_some_method")
def test_some_stuff(mock_some_obj_some_method):
    mock_some_obj_some_method.return_value = False
```

Comment: I don't think your code will execute - `some_obj` is not a module to import, it's a local variable in `some_method`.

Comment: Wouldn't it work if you import `SomeObject` from the file where `some_other_method` is returning it??. I'll test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @hoefling for the critical piece with `return_value.object_method_name.return_value` which was super confusing when I first saw it.

First, here's trivial code `sscce.py` to be tested, it's in a Python module called `my_sscee_module`. This is a little contrived, but I wanted it to be as short as humanly possible.  The code creates an instance of a class from the third-party library `pymisp` and calls one object method.

```
from pymisp import PyMISP
misp_url = 'http://bogus.misp.org'
misp_key = 'redacted'


def orgs() -> list:
    # fetch and return the list of organisations
    client = PyMISP(url=misp_url, key=misp_key)
    return client.organisations(pythonify=True)
```

To test, I need to mock the class constructor (so that it doesn't connect over the network) and that one object method. Here's the test file with mocks to exercise the trivial code:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from my_sscce_module import sscce


# mock the class to intercept calls to the __init__ method
# note this uses the location where the class is looked up,
# not the location where the PyMISP class is defined
@patch('my_sscce_module.sscce.PyMISP')
def test_sscce(mock_pymisp):
    # define the expected result
    exp_orgs = ['org1', 'org2']
    # mock the object method to return a fixed value
    mock_pymisp.return_value.organisations.return_value = exp_orgs
    # call the function under test
    act_orgs = sscce.orgs()
    # assert that a class instance was created
    mock_pymisp.assert_called()
    # check for the expected result
    assert act_orgs == exp_orgs
```

However I still do not know how to mock *multiple return values* from an object method. For example, the first time the mock is called, return organization 'foo', and the second time the mock is called, return 'bar'. This is easy with a standalone python function, just call mocker with `side_effect` instead of `return_value`.